# Can connect to FTP, but no data is transferred

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I just installed and started `vsftpd` on my Fedora 20 machine and try to connect as a normal Unix user to that FTP server. Connecting works, but I cannot get any data:

```
ftp> open
(to) 192.168.3.41
Connected to 192.168.3.41 (192.168.3.41).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (192.168.3.41:myname): 
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,3,41,77,211).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Transfer done (but failed to open directory).
```

Permissions on the dir are owned by the `myname` user. Another user does work.

I disabled the firewall, but it doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It was an SELinux problem. I disabled SELinux and it works now.

(I know I shouldn't disable SELinux, but configure it correctly, but this is a development machine and having to deal with firewalls and SELinux during development is a PITA, so I always disabled them completely.)